# Rails AWS config file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to run this import task from my heroku rails app which connects to AWS and grabs a CSV but get the following error (full error shown below):

**ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code in my initializers/aws.rb file where I put my credentials:**

```
Aws.config.update({
 region: 'us-east-2',
 credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id: 
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})
```

---

**Here is the task(in one of my rake files):**

```
    desc "import for CSV to S3"
    task import: [:environment] do
     s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-east-2', credentials: credentials)
     File.open('nba_data.csv', 'wb') do |file|
      reap = s3.get_object({ bucket: 'nba-api', key: 'nba_data.csv'}, target: file)
      csv_text = File.read('nba_data.csv')
      csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
      csv.each do |row|
       Player.create!(row.to_hash.except("id"))
    end
  end
end
```

---

**This is the full console error**

Franks-MacBook-Air:nba_site frankburke$ heroku run rails player_query:import
Running rails player_query:import on ⬢ protected-tundra-94123... up, run.3454 (Free)
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.19.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/credentials.rb:7:in `initialize'
/app/config/initializers/aws.rb:4:in`new'
/app/config/initializers/aws.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in`load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in`load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in`block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in`load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in`each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in`require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in`run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in`'
Tasks: TOP => player_query:import => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try to change this...

```
Aws.config.update({
 region: 'us-east-2',
 credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id: 
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})
```

to this

```
Aws.config.update({
 region: 'us-east-2',
 credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the change and ran it and now get this error

NameError: undefined local variable or method `credentials' for main:Object
/app/lib/tasks/player_query.rake:242:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

===================================================

Here is line 242:

      s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-east-2', credentials: credentials)

Comment: This is the line - s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-east-2', credentials: credentials)

Comment: not sure why it is saying credentials is undefined.

Comment: when you configure this second block of code with the credentials itself, it works?
For example, instead of
`s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-east-2', credentials: credentials)` to be something like
`Aws::S3::Client.new(
  access_key_id: creds['access_key_id'],
  secret_access_key: creds['secret_access_key'],
  region:'us-east-2',
  credentials: credentials`
)`

It seems that the code body its not recognizing your "credentials" as it was not declared, check if you can access Client.new with the credentials, and then we can exclude that the problem is caused by something else...

Comment: I commented out the aws.rb code.  and changed the second block to this - s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], region:'us-east-2')

Comment: Got this error: Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options:
  - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
  - :credentials
  - :credentials_provider